# Let $Y = X^2$. Find the pdf of Y when the distribution is $N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, self-learning

I've performed a change of variable:
$$X = \sqrt{y}$$
$$X'=\frac{1}{2}Y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
Thus:
$$f(\sqrt{y})*X'=f(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$$
However the book gives:
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Arkamis That one is about the characteristic function, not about the pdf.

Comment: @Behaviour Yes, I must have copied the URL wrong question and not noticed.

Comment: @Arkamis I added an exact duplicate now.

Comment: @Behaviour Thanks, that might have even been the question I tried to link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You should consider $P(-\sqrt{x}<y<\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. I computed only half the result. To complete the solution:

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}},0<y<\infty$$